# How to filter files based on file name format in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to dowload files from a FTP server with a certain file name format. The file names in the server may look like this:

1. O-0098-00009801_08052014054258.xml
2. ORDER ID 3359_08062014121815.xml
3. O-0302-00022043_07312014085513.xml
4. O-LABELS_94920235569876.XML
5. JO ANN_08062014170911.xml
6. O-0233-00026378_07312014155245.xml
7. LABELS_08052014174907.xml

I only want to download files if name format is O-XXXX-XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xml

I was using the following code but it is not very effective. What would be the most effective way to only select the files with file name format mentioned above?

```
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            fileName = reader.ReadLine();
            if (fileName.ToUpper().IndexOf("O-") > -1)
                files.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

The result would be to only select these files:

1. O-0098-00009801_08052014054258.xml
2. O-0233-00026378_07312014155245.xml
3. O-0302-00022043_07312014085513.xml

Comment: Sounds like a regex problem: "O-\d{4}-\d{8}_\d{14}.xml"

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Connecting to the FTP server?  Getting a list of all files?  Parsing file names?  Downloading an individual file?  Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I second the use of regular expressions for this in any case it's just matching the filename that's the problem. I think the pattern is pretty obvious anyway. For all else, *vague*. Kindly provide more details and some sample code for best possible communication.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I apologize if my question was not clear. Steve provided the answer I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you have the filelist already stored in a `List<string>` the extraction is simple

```
List<string> files = new List<string>()
{
    "O-0098-00009801_08052014054258.xml",
    "ORDER ID 3359_08062014121815.xml",
    "O-0302-00022043_07312014085513.xml",
    "O-LABELS_94920235569876.XML",
    "JO ANN_08062014170911.xml",
    "O-0233-00026378_07312014155245.xml",
    "LABELS_08052014174907.xml"
};

Regex r = new Regex(@"O-\d{4}-\d{8}_\d{14}");
var result = files.Where(x => r.IsMatch(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially just do:

```
List<string> orders = new List<string>()
{
    "O-0098-00009801_08052014054258.xml",
    "ORDER ID 3359_08062014121815.xml",
    "O-0302-00022043_07312014085513.xml",
    "O-LABELS_94920235569876.XML",
    "JO ANN_08062014170911.xml",
    "O-0233-00026378_07312014155245.xml",
    "LABELS_08052014174907.xml"
};

List<string> valid = new List<string>()
{
    "O-0098-00009801_08052014054258.xml",
    "O-0302-00022043_07312014085513.xml",
    "O-0233-00026378_07312014155245.xml"
};

List<string> order = orders.Where(x => valid.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

If you had a `List` of valid / total you could do it in the above manner.  Otherwise you could use Regular Expressions like Steve answered.